# How to convert an octet string to readable string

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

For example I get an octet string as follow:
3c3f786d6c2076657273696f6e3d22312e302220656e636f64696e673d225554462d38223f3e3c53
6f6170456e763a456e76656c6f706520786d6c6e733a536f6170456e763d22687474703a2f2f7363
68656d61732e786d6c736f61702e6f72672f736f61702f656e76656c6f70652f223e3c536f617045
6e763a48656164657220786d6c6e733a7773613d22687474703a2f2f7777772e77332e6f72672f32
3030352f30382f61646472657373696e67223e3c7773613a46726f6d3e3c7773613a416464726573
733e43484e594442473c2f7773613a416464726573733e3c2f7773613a46726f6d3e3c7773613a54
6f3e434352433c2f7773613a546f3e3c7773613a416374696f6e3e687474703a2f2f636372632e73
6572766963652e62616e6b636f6d6d2e636f6d2f6162737472616374696f6e2f61746f6d69632f74
6563686e6963616c2e506572736f6e616c4372656469745265706f7274536572762f4661756c743c
2f7773613a416374696f6e3e3c7773613a4d65737361676549443e75726e3a757569643a30303031

And I know the underlying text is UTF-8 encoding, so who can offer some methods to convert these octets to readable string?

Comment: Answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try reading each two characters, parsing them as a base 16 integer with [`Integer.parseInt(String,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), adding them to a byte array, and constructing a [`String` from the result](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29):

```java
public static String fromHex(String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  byte bs[] = new byte[s.length() / 2];
  for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i+=2) {
    bs[i/2] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i+2), 16);
  }
  return new String(bs, "UTF8");
}

fromHex("48656c6c6f2c20576f726c6421"); // => "Hello, World!"
```

Your string example looks like an XML document containing a SOAP message.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here at [OctetString](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/smi/OctetString.html) from snmp4j. This can be helpful for you.

```
OctetString octetString = new OctetString(java.lang.String);
octetString.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to convert it into a byte array first and then building the string, look into Byte class to see if it has a method for getting the byte out of two hex chars, then it would be only a matter of iterating through every two chars and convering them to bytes.

This link may be useful [Byte parseByte with radix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)